# Bootstrap4 How Can I Display Inner Div While Hiding Outer Div on Resize?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a chart inside of a card. When being viewed on small or xs screen, I'd like for the card to be hidden but for the chart to still continue to be displayed.  I can hide the card easy enough through bootstrap with "d-none d-sm-block", but it makes the chart disappear as well.  I was hoping I could simply override the outer div command by placing "d-block" in the chart div, but it does not appear to be that simple.

So does anybody know how I can continue to show the inner chart div, while hiding the outer card div on smaller screens?  I've created a very simplistic [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BigSexy/sztk8jxu/4/) that you can resize to see what's going on.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card card-cascade wider reverse d-none d-sm-block" style="background-color: lightsteelblue">
      <div class="view view-cascade overlay">
        <div class="row justify-content-center d-block mt-3">
          <div class="col d-inline">
            1 of 2
          </div>
          <div class="col d-inline">
            2 of 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think media query can help you.

Look at the jsfiddle code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/ckfhrqLa/)

```
.card{
   background-color: lightsteelblue
}
@media (max-width: 400px) { 
    .card{
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}
```